# Spring mvc: Change response object in postHandle in HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, cookies, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am trying to save the latest time in the cookie. So after every controller call I have intercepting the call using a postHandle of HandlerInterceptor. In that I am updating the value in the cookie. But the values is not updating. Anyone have any idea why it is not working.

The code:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView ex)
            throws Exception {

        boolean isSet = true;
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute("userId") != null){
                for (Cookie cookies: request.getCookies()) {
                    if ("RequestTime".equals(cookies.getName())) {
                        isSet = false;
                         cookies.setValue(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                         response.addCookie(cookies);
                }
            }
            if(isSet){
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("RequestTime", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create cookie ,you should set cookie's path, when you want to share this cookie in your project,you should set cookie path as "/" like

```
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("userId") != null){
       Cookie cookie = new Cookie("RequestTime",Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
       cookie.setPath("/")
       response.addCookie(cookie); }
```

the default cookie path is current request URL.

NOTE: if you want to share the cookie from different subdomain, you should also set cookie domain.

`cookie.setDomain(".test.com")`

Comment: Hi Guys,

After reading few article in come to know that if we are setting cookie in the postHandle then it wont work properly. So I moved my code from posthandle to preHandle block.

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: You can update cookie in preHandle but not in postHandle, We probably need a ControllerAdvice